# An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, arguments

I wanna send an argument from an override function on my MainActivity to use on an interface to changue an URL everytime that i made click on a drop down list.

On my MainActivity i have:

before the class definition:

```
var item2:String="popular"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

on the same activity:

```
    override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long)
{
    val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
    item2=item

}
```

and in the interface:

```
val get_url:String ="/3/movie/$item2?api_key=KEY_NUMBER"
interface MovieApiInterface {
    @GET(get_url)
    fun getMovieList(): Call<MovieResponse>

}
```

But there i have "An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant"

Don't understand why :(

Thanks

Comment: Nop i read it before. 
But i think maybe is because im trying to use a var instead of val

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually pretty descriptive, you can only pass compile-time constants as arguments to annotations, so you'll need to replace:

```
val get_url:String ="/3/movie/$item2?api_key=KEY_NUMBER"
interface MovieApiInterface {
    @GET(get_url)
    fun getMovieList(): Call<MovieResponse>

}
```

with:

```
interface MovieApiInterface {
    @GET("/3/movie/$item2?api_key=KEY_NUMBER")
    fun getMovieList(): Call<MovieResponse>

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. The error is still there 

Comment: `$item2` looks like a variable reference - you can't use that in an annotation either, as that would prevent the string from being a compile-time constant.

Comment: yeah, I noticed it. I could resolve it, the error was that retrofit doest acept this kind of sustitucion on their lines, u should use {} instead a $, and declare the id on the funcion below. __ @GET("/3/movie/{id}?api_key=bb259118f01c72338a5e8a5dc72d7701") __ fun getMovieList(@Path("id") id:String): Call<MovieResponse>__Thaks for your help!